# Regarding Carriage Returns

Tags: linux, windows, shell, unix, carriage-return

I have created an `sh` script in Unix and it basically compiles a program specified via argument, for example: `sh shellFile cprogram.c`, and feeds the compiled program a variety of input files.

These input files are created in Unix and i have tested it, I am happy with those results. I have even tested it out with input files, made in Unix, that even had an extra carriage return at the end and yet i get good results, lets name this test file `00ecr` for reference. Is it possible that if i created a test file in windows and transferred it over to Unix, that this new test file, lets call it `00wind`, will produce bad results in my shell program.

This is just a theoretical question overall. I am just wondering if it will muck things up even though I tested my shell script with files, made in Unix, that accounted for extra carriage returns?

Answer (score 1):

How about in your script, you use Linux command `file` to identify if the file has Windows style line terminations:

```
$file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

So your script could have a converting function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

windows_file=`file $1 | grep CRLF`

if [[ -z "$windows_file" ]]; then
    echo "File already in unix format"
else
    # file need converting
    dos2unix $1
    echo "Converted a windows file"
fi
```

So here we first use the `file` utility to output the file type, and grep `CRLF` string, to see if the file needs converting. The grep will return `null` if it's not in windows format,  and we can test for null string with `if [[ -z "$var" ]]` statement.

And then just `dos2unix` utility to convert it:

```
$ dos2unix test.txt
dos2unix: converting file test.txt to Unix format ...
$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text
```

This way you could ensure that your input is always "sanitized".

Comment: I have thought about that but i actually want to know if it it does muck up my results. Its mainly to see if i have to change my code or not.

Comment: @user3470766, you could try converting your files manually to "windows style" with `unix2dos` to see what happens. Nevertheless, never leave things to chance, and sanitize your inputs